# How to find cyrillic word in text

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to find the word `"пак"` in text like this: `180121-5пак`. There are Cyrillic signs.

I tried to use the `Pos()` function, but there is no effect. The function returns value 0.

```cpp
bool f( String Zal )
{
  if ( Zal.Pos(_D("пак")) != 0 || Zal.Pos(_D("УТ")) != 0 )
  {
   smth
  }
  return true;
}
```

I tried to use `UnicodeString("пак")`, `AnsiString("пак")` and `UTF8String("пак")`, but without results.

Answer (score 0):

`"пак"` is a *narrow* string literal, and thus subject to the charset that your source file is saved as, and that which the compiler uses to parse your source file.  Since `UnicodeString` holds a UTF-16 string, you should use a *wide* string literal instead, eg:

```cpp
Zal.Pos( L"пак" )
```

However, `UnicodeString` uses different data types on different platforms (`wchar_t` on Windows, `char16_t` on Posix), so you should use the `_D()` macro to map your string literal to the correct data type for each platform your project is targeting, eg:

```cpp
Zal.Pos( _D("пак") )
```

Comment: `L` and `_D` doesn't work. Its mean that `L""` is the same as `_D("")`

Comment: @Jacek `_D(“”)` maps to `L””` on Windows, `u””` on Posix. But what exactly is not working for you? How are you setting `Zal` to begin with? Please update your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: The `if()` condition does not return an expected non-zero value. A file that contains the specified string should be removed inside the function `if()`, but the condition is not met

Comment: @Jacek you are just restating the problem, but you still have not shown how `Zal` is being assigned its character data to begin with. `f(_D("180121-5пак"))` should work, but I doubt that is what you are really doing. So what is the actual input?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `TIdAttachment* Attachment = dynamic_cast<TIdAttachment*>( IdMessage1->MessageParts->Items[j] ); f(Attachment->FileName)` I`m sorry.

Comment: @Jacek ok, so what is `Attachment->FileName` set to exactly? Have you tried debugging the `FileName` to look at the individual chars? In UTF-16, `"пак"` is chars `$043F $0430 $043A` and `"180121-5пак"` is chars `$0031 $0038 $0030 $0031 $0032 $0031 $002D $0035 $043F $0430 $043A`, is that what you are seeing? `UnicodeString(_D("180121-5пак")).Pos(_D("пак"))` should be returning 9 in that case..

Comment: Yes, I just iterating `"180121-5пак"` to decimal `int(Zal[i])` and three last charakters have value:`1087,1072,1082`. Yes this example return 9 but in this way: `UnicodeString a = "180121-5пак";a.Pos(_D("пак"));` there is still 0

Comment: `UnicodeString a = "180121-5пак";` is wrong, it will perform an ANSI-to-Unicode conversion that causes data loss on the `пак`. It needs to be `UnicodeString a = L"180121-5пак";` or `UnicodeString a = _D("180121-5пак");` to avoid any data loss.

Comment: But this is fairly moot when testing with a string literal. The real issue is you are getting a string from somewhere else, and `Pos()` is failing on that string, so the most likely culprit is data loss on that string. Especially since it is coming from an email. What does the raw email data look like? Unicode filenames are tricky to handle in emails. What do the chars in `Attachment->FileName` look like when you iterate them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227719/discussion-between-jacek-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: I have iterated it and cast to int. It look likes 204, 224, 240 .... This is the sam with IdMessage1->Subject. Subjest text: 'Ìàðòèíþę Îëåęńłé' but in meesage: 'Мартинюк Олексій'

Comment: @Jacek again, what does the RAW email data look like? "*It look likes 204, 224, 240 ....*" - those are bytes `0xCC 0xE0 0xF0`. Email standards don't allow *unescaped* non-ASCII characters in email headers, and Indy's email parser certainly doesn't, either. Typically, most email composers encode non-ASCII characters in [RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) or similar format, but you don't appear to be receiving that.

Comment: what program is the best for raw data?

Comment: @Jacek log the raw data you are loading into the `TIdMessage`. If that is coming from a socket (ie, `TIdPOP3` or `TIdIMAP4`), then Indy has various `TIdLog...` components that you can attach to the client's `Intercept` property to log the raw socket data.

Comment: Raw data looks like: <EOL>Subject: RE: Đ’Ń–Đ´ĐżŃ€Đ°Đ˛ĐşĐ° Đ˛Đ°ĐłĐ¸ Đ˝Đ° GHG<EOL>. Subject in Outlook: Відправка ваги на  GHG

Comment: <EOL>Subject: =?windows-1251?B?0vDo9/PqIMKz6vLu8A==?=<EOL>

Comment: And attachments in xlsx: <EOL> name="=?windows-1251?Q?120822-4_=D3=D2.xlsx?="<EOL>Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64<EOL>Content-Disposition: attachment;<EOL> filename="=?windows-1251?Q?120822-4_=D3=D2.xlsx?="<EOL>

Comment: @Jacek that first Subject is just raw unencoded bytes and will not decode properly, unless you assign a Russian encoding to the client's IOHandler. But the rest are all using RFC2047 and should decode fine.

Comment: I'd like to read the charset from the message and manually convert chars from cp1251 to unicode on that basis. Example: if ( IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieve( UID, IdMessage1 ) ) String s = IdMessage1->CharSet; But string 's' is empty. Is other way to read charset from message?